# Don't want certain column to be printed in the excel file using Displaytag

Tags: jsp, servlets, export, export-to-excel, displaytag

I have a Display Tag which has columns. In last two Columns , there are links.So when I am using  export excel, the links are getting printed in the excel file which i don't want. How can I only print certain columns. My Display tag is as given

```
    <display:table name="requestScope.List" pagesize="10"
                               export="true" sort="list" id="itemName" class="displaytag" requestURI="">  
                    <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="/ReportBeanServlet"  />
                    <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" />
                    <display:column  property="occid" title=" Occupant ID" style="text-align:center;" media="all" ></display:column>
                    <display:column  property="firstName" title="First Name" style="text-align:center;" media="all" ></display:column>
                    <display:column  property="lastName" title="Last Name" style="text-align:center;"  media="all" ></display:column>
                    <display:column  property="sonOf" title="Father's Name" style="text-align:center;" media="all"  ></display:column>
                    <display:column  property="district" title="District" style="text-align:center;" media="all"  ></display:column>
                    <display:column  property="village" title="Village"  style="text-align:center;" media="all" ></display:column>

                    <display:column  title="Reservation Form" style="text-align:center;" media="all">
                        <a href="javascript:toggle1('${itemName.occid}')">
                            Show reservation details
                        </a>
                    </display:column>

                    <display:column  title="Agreement Form" style="text-align:center;" media="all">
                        <a href="javascript:toggle2('${itemName.occid}')">
                            Show agreement details
                        </a>
                    </display:column>

                    <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true" />
                </display:table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `media="html"` in href column so it doesn't export those columns

code changed in the above snippet::

```
display:column title="Agreement Form"   media="html"
display:column title="Reservation Form" media="html"
```